# Error de codigo que me sale: 1value required as left operand of assignment

Tags: c++, array, string

Estoy intentando cerrar el ciclo después de que ya no detecte ningún char pero me sale el error:

1value required as left operand of assignment

en la linea de del if

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int i;
string f;

f="Palabra";

for(i=0;i<=23;i++)
{
    cout<< f[i]<<endl;
    if(f[i] =! 'A' || f[i] =! 'B' || f[i] =! 'C' || f[i] =! 'D' || f[i] =! 'E' || f[i] =! 'F' || f[i] =! 'G' || f[i] =! 'H' || f[i] =! 'I' || f[i] =! 'J' || f[i] =! 'K' || f[i] =! 'L' || f[i] =! 'M' || f[i] =! 'N' || f[i] =! 'O' || f[i] =! 'P' || f[i] =! 'Q' || f[i] =! 'R' || f[i] =! 'S' || f[i] =! 'T' || f[i] =! 'U' || f[i] =! 'V' || f[i] =! 'W' || f[i] =! 'X' || f[i] =! 'Y' || f[i] =! 'Z')
    {
        i=23;
    }
}


return 0;
```

}

Comment: No es `=!` es `!=`.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Es posible que tengas un typo y donde pones =! realmente quieras escribir !=

```
 if(f[i] != 'A' || f[i] != 'B' ....
```